# Build Dynamic Google Search Link Using Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-finance

I am hoping to create a column in Excel that links to a Google search for a specific stock depending on the stock symbol in column A. For instance if column A1 = `AAPL`,

b1 would be:

Using the Symbol in A1, cell b1 will create a link that makes Google search. I know this can be done in google sheets but I'm not sure of the exact syntax.

Comment: you mean like: https://www.google.com/search?q=AAPL ?

Comment: yes like that but using the symbol in cell a1 to create the full link in cell b1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
="https://www.google.com/search?q="&A1
```

[image]

---

```
=HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/search?q="&A1, "search now")
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/search?q="&A1:A2, 
 "search for "&A1:A2))
```

[image]

---

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE(A1, "price")
```

[image]

Comment: you have been quite helpful to me this week!